# Mercury Mail Server Chash

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP (using xamp)  application to make medical appointments, that every morning sends mails to every patient who has reservation. 
I send mail through Mercury Mail Server. Running on Windows 7.
My problem is that after a few days of running (like a week)  , mercury crases, and windows shows an "insufficient memory" error.
The computer is a brand new athlon 2 x2 250 with 4gb of memory en 500gb.
The number of emails sent per day the server are not many, can be 100 at most.
Can anyone help me ? or recommend another mail server ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Paging File size can be a problem. Can you try and increase the paging file size and check? Another possible reason, may be that one of the processes is leaking handles. You can check this from the Task manager, if the handles count is increasing frequently (every few seconds or so).